# Nested google map 2.0 fragment shows static picture

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-nested-fragment

I have a problem with displaying google map fragment in view pager. I have an activity, viewpager in it, and in one of the fragments in viewpager there is a google map 2.0 fragment.

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_profile_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="@string/about_screen_info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/banner_bf" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/about_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:tag="AboutMapFragment"
        map:mapType="normal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment class:

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = AboutFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    public static AboutFragment newInstance() {
        AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.about_map);

        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.about_map, mapFragment).commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        if (map == null) {
            map = mapFragment.getMap();
            if(map != null){
                Log.d(TAG, "map in AboutFragment initialized!");
                drawPositionOnMap();
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "map in AboutFragment is null!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawPositionOnMap() {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(20, 50);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getCurrentSlidingMenu().addIgnoredView(view.findViewById(R.id.about_map));
    }
}
```

So, the problems is the following: when I switch to this fragment, map seems to initialize, but instead of moveable map I see static map snapshot centered on 0,0 coordinates.

[image]

BUT! if I lock device screen and then unlock it, map initializes normally!

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved using getFragmentManager() instead getChildFragmentManager(), I was using the same implementation:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, fragment).commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

I changed that and my problem was solved...I hope this help you too.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to initialize your map onActivityCreated?

```
 if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.about_map, mapFragment).commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
 if (map == null) {
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        if(map != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "map in AboutFragment initialized!");
            drawPositionOnMap();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "map in AboutFragment is null!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've just tried, mapFragment.getMap() returns null, if initialize it in onActivityCreated(), though mapFragment.getMap() in onResume() returns actual map instance. But again, picture is static

Comment: You have to call `drawPositionOnMap()` so that your view focus on the point that you want. Let me now if that works.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. But I found out, that this bug appears only on 2.3.4 Android OS, on 4.0 and higher maps works fine. I think it's OS issue.